# Deploying Android app to server

Tags: android, google-play

Do i have to deploy the android app on a server before publishing to Appstore. Would appreciate if anyone can point me to some of the popular/cheaper server avenues!

Comment: no you dont have to deploy android app on a server before publishing it to appstore. I am curious what led you to think that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do i have to deploy the android app on a server before publishing to
>   Appstore

No it's not compulsory to deploy your app in some server before publish in play store. It's dependent on you if your client or any enterprise required to access your app for particular used or for testing purpose then to deploy in some server.

Here i saw you some of apps deploy server available in Market

1. **ADF Mobile Deploys** :Before you can publish an application for distribution to end users, you must test it on a simulator or on an actual device to assess its behavior and ease of use. By deploying an Android application package (.apk) file to the platform-appropriate device or simulator, `ADF Mobile` enables you to test applications before publishing them to the application marketplace, such as Google Play.

   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/doc.111240/e24475/deploying.htm
2. **TestFlight**: [Official Page](https://www.testflightapp.com/)
3. **JenKins** : [Official Page](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/23/ci-with-jenkins-for-ios-apps-build-distribution-via-testflightapp-tutorial/)
4. **HockeyApp**: [Official Page](http://hockeyapp.net/)
5. **Apphance**: [Official Page](http://www.applause.com/mobile-sdk)
6. **Google Play Native App Beta Testing**: [Official Page](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/)

There are more alternatives available in market for more information go to http://www.applause.com/mobile-sdk